# use rsync to backup home directory to external hard-drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, rsync

I have a movable hard-drive that I would like to use to backup my data using rsync command. To accomplish that I would navigate to the directory of my external hard-drive (target directory) and run:

```
rsync -av --delete /home/diego ./
```

While running I get few failures, for examaple:

```
rsync: send_files failed to open "/home/diego/.viminfo": Permission denied (13)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/home/diego/pfsense.img": Permission denied (13)
```

Now, those file are owned by root in my home directory. My question is what should I use to fix that:

1) The over-mentioned command with sudo:

```
 sudo rsync -av --delete /home/diego ./
```

2) The switch used for ssh

```
rsync -av --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --delete /home/diego ./
```

3) Something else

and what is the difference between 1) and 2) ? thanks

Comment: I would do `sudo chown username:username .viminfo` (and the other file too), and then retry the original `rsync` command. There is rarely a good reason for files in your home directory to be owned by root or anyone else.

Comment: What if those file are many? i.e. the output of `find /home/diego -group root | wc -l` is 2660.  I have many files from cloned repos that belongs to root..

Comment: The short answer would be `chown -r diego:diego ~` but if you have cloned repo's in there, that *might* be a good reason to have different owners.

Comment: So in this case , the `sudo rsync -av --delete /home/diego  ./` can be an option?

Comment: Yes. `sudo rsync -av` will preserve ownership and permissions.

Comment: can use also `--progress` or `-P` option for display progress